# Edit encoding of sensor_msgs/Image message

Tags: ros-melodic, sensor-msgs, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a [sensor_msgs/Image message](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html) that I'm unable to use with standard ROS packages like stereo_image_proc because the "encoding" is described as "8UC1". I want it to be interpreted as "mono8" and want to change the string in the "encoding" parameter of the message.

```
void imageCallback(sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
    ROS_INFO("Message received");
    msg->encoding.at<std::string>(0,0) = "mono8";
}
```

When I do it like above I get the error message "type name is not allowed" when compiling. I have tried all sorts of alternatives but can't seem to find it out. Can anyone help me on this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319123/edit-encoding-of-sensor_msgs/image-message/) by [eirikaso](https://answers.ros.org/users/10741/eirikaso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2019-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

8UC1 is the equivalent openCV encoding of ros' mono8, they describe the same thing. However you must use one with openCV functions and the other with ROS functions.

I think this problem is to do with how you're accessing the variable. There are few problems, it's a const data type so you will not be able to modify it. Even it is wasn't const you should update it as below:

```
msg->encoding = "mono8";
```

I don't know what you're trying to do with that line, it looks like you're trying to access a pixel and set it to a type string. Are you trying to convert this ROS image message into an openCV image? If so there is a built in library cv_bridge for doing that with [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials).

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eirikaso](https://answers.ros.org/users/10741/eirikaso/) on 2019-03-21**:
Thank you. I have recorded some .bag files with the Intel realsense camera using their ROS driver. Unfortunately they save them as 8UC1 encoded. I will try to use cv_bridge instead tomorrow, but I got a tip that I should be able to just change the encoding string [link](https://github.com/intel-ros/realsense/issues/253#issuecomment-472029833)

I will try to subscribe, apply cv_bridge, and then publish again

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-03-22**:
If you just need change the encoding string. You'll need to first make a non-const copy of the message and then update the encoding as I've shown in my answer, then you will be able to re-publish the updated message

**Comment by [eirikaso](https://answers.ros.org/users/10741/eirikaso/) on 2019-03-22**:
Yes, thank you. I just tested it 30 minutes ago and got it working :)